# C programming having trouble creating files in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm programming a simple Load Balancer as part of a course, and in order to inform the servers and browser of the ports I bind to, I save them as a simple file in the same directory, which they can then read. The issue is that even though both ports i'm creating are using the same function, one of the files is not being created. I've gone over the code over and over and I cannot find the issue.
Basically, only the file http_port is being created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "LB.h"

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, server_socket, http_socket, client_socket, servers[3];
    char *server_port = "server_port", *http_port = "http_port";
    http_socket = Get_Socket(http_port);
    server_socket = Get_Socket(server_port); //continues to load balancer

//inside functions.c
int Get_Socket(char* filename)
{
    int port, bind_state = -1;
    int new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    do
    {
        port = get_random_port(PORT_MIN, PORT_MAX);
        socket_address.sin_port = htons(port);
        new_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        bind_state = bind(new_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));

    } while (bind_state < 0);
    Write_Port2File(filename, port);
    return new_socket;
}

void Write_Port2File(char* filename, int port)
{
    printf("%s", filename);
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    fprintf(fp, "%d", port);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I'd appreciate any and all advice you can provide towards solving this issue.

P.S. It seems the problem only occurs after I enable the permissions for the folder with chmod 755 * and chmod 777 . (which is part of the course requirements).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `perror()` say when you try to open the second file?

Comment: OT: This loop `while (bind_state < 0);` might leak socket descriptors. You want to close `new_socket` in case the call to `bind()` failed. Also the call to `socket()` is missing error checking.

Comment: Perhaps `get_random_port()` messes things up?

Comment: Who is owning "*the folder*" and is the owner different from the user running the program? Is the program started with "*the folder*" being the current work directory?

Comment: Are there any stale versions of the two files in question inside "*the folder*"?

Comment: I delete all stale versions of the files, even though I don't believe that should be an issue as the tag "w" overwrites existing versions.

Comment: I am the owner of the folder and i set permissions for the files so that anyone can access them

Comment: it seems the problem was bind going into an infinite loop. I'm investigating